# Missing Service Applications

Tags: managed-metadata, term-store

When I attempted to access term store management I received an error:

```
The Managed Metadata Service or Connection is currently not available. The Application Pool or Managed Metadata Web Service may not have been started. Please Contact your Administrator.
```

I then checked my service applications and noticed that many were missing, as seen here. Including the service relating to term management and metadata.

[image]

I then attempted to perform an upgrade on sharepoint using

```
./psconfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures
```

This was the result.

[image]

However after this there was no change to the list of service applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. I promoted the server to a domain controller and reconfigured the sharepoint instance. Once I performed those actions all of the service applications were available to me.